# implementing an identity provider for webrtc

Tags: webrtc

Is there any implementation of webrtc containing an interaction with an idenitity provider (idp)? since all the open source Webrtc platforme that i've seen (easyrtc, peerjs, ...) dont include an interaction with an idp.

For example there is no implemenation, calling the function setting the IdP --> setIdentityProvider()

So my intent is to have an open source Webrtc platforme (already implementing the interaction function) able to communicate with my own IdP , and after that i will try to figure out how to do the communication between them (websocket, https, ...)

Comment: I think you are talking about `signaling`, not `webrtc`. `Webrtc` is just a spec, defining two `API`s. One `API` manages fetching devices, encoding/decoding, data streams, etc... It provides callbacks for you to handle the rest. The other `API` is the `javascript` `API`, browsers can implement the low-level `API` and expose that functionality to web developers through `javascript`.

Comment: Just to be clear, maybe i didn't explain it well, In WebRTC, there are 3 APIs (MediaStream, PeerConnection and DataChannel), in these APIs every thing is defined (even my probleme is defined --> check W3C spec for WebRTC and you will find the identity part) but in the open source of webrtc there no implementation of the IdP connection part

Comment: I don't understand why your question is downvoted. Related links: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-security-arch-13 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API#Identity_and_security
Unfortunately no real implementation yet, and that's a pity because we could finally have decentralized calling (as we have in regular telephony) and not islands of silos.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has an implementation of the identity provider part of the spec which seems to be enabled by default.

Chrome does not implement this yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you are right about Chrome, but for Mozilla they don't have the implementation, but they do have the API.